# US Canada Border Immigration on Amtrak Train

Tags: visas, usa, canada, amtrak

I am on H1 visa living in Seattle and planning to go for some vacation to Vancouver by Amtrak train.

I have few questions regarding immigration happening.

1. Where would it happen at Canada Side, while entering into Canada?
2. Where would it happen at USA Side, while entering back into USA?

Answer (score 2):

## Seattle to Vancouver

When arriving at the train station and checking-in your passport and documents will be checked. Your documents will also be checked when arriving at Vancouver.

The [Amtrak website](https://www.amtrak.com/crossing-the-us-canadian-border) provides some guidance for this:

> ## When Travelling
>
> The form of identification you carry with you on your trip should be the same piece of ID that you selected and provided details about when you made your reservation.
>
> You must carry the original, valid identification document. Copies, expired or otherwise invalid documents will not be accepted. Each passenger must have his or her own ID.

It is recommended to arrive 1 hour before departure.

[Amtrak Cascades from Seattle to Vancouver - What is the border crossing like northbound?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/amtrak-cascades-from-seattle-to-vancouver-what-is-the-border-crossing-like-nor) summarises this nicely:

> For reference this train does Canada Customs clearance on arrival at Pacific Central Station in Vancouver, not at the border.

## Vancouver to Seattle

There will be a check at the station in Vancouver and another customs check when the train arrives in the USA.

It is also recommended to arrive 1 hour before departure.

Comment: "As such, there won't be any US CBP around if you need to get an exit stamp." Just saying, a US exit stamp doesn't even exist. Also, the passport check is at Vancouver; the second check is a pure customs check

Comment: Ohh there would be no US exit stamps. So, will there be any change in i94 travel records or we need to get that separately? Or its not required?

Comment: @hatellla on Amtrak’s website it says: *Non-US-resident citizens of other countries entering the United States must also apply for the I-94 Arrival Record and pay a $6 fee. To expedite the process, you may pre-pay the fee and apply online through the US Customs website up to seven (7) days before your trip. Then you’ll just complete the final steps onboard. If you choose to do this all onboard, you must have $6 cash in US funds (exact change) to submit along with your form.*

Comment: @hatellla The Canadians will pass it on to the US. However, since you're a resident with an H1B visa, it doesn't really matter to you